# Polymer Paper-Radio-Group - how to have multiple radio buttons with the same name

Tags: forms, polymer, paper-elements

I'm using Paper Elements from the Polymer Project to build a form, and have run into a problem using the `paper-radio-group` tag and its children, `paper-radio-button`.  With a normal radio button list, I would do the following:

```
<input type="radio" name="myFieldName" value="MyFirstOption" />
<input type="radio" name="myFieldName" value="MySecondOption" />
<input type="radio" name="myFieldName" value="MyThirdOption" />
```

Note that the `name` attributes are the same, grouping the radio buttons and producing a single value for the `myFieldName` field.  However using the `paper-radio-group` element in the same way does not work:

```
<paper-radio-group label="My Field">
  <paper-radio-button name="myFieldName" label="First"></paper-radio-button>
  <paper-radio-button name="myFieldName" label="Second"></paper-radio-button>
  <paper-radio-button name="myFieldName" label="Third"></paper-radio-button>
</paper-radio-group>
```

This produces three radio buttons, but selecting one doesn't deselect the others.  If I give each a unique name then it works from a UI perspective, but is different than the standard radio button behaviour.

In addition to this, where do I specify the value for each radio button?  There is a label property, but nothing for value.  Am I going to have to wire up a hidden field to the `change` event of the `paper-radio-button`, or the `core-select` event on the `paper-radio-group`?  Neither seems like a particularly elegant solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question is quite old and probably the property did not exist at the time, but at least now a days we can have the same `name` attribute in `paper-radio-buttons` that belong to a `paper-radio-group` if we select a different `attr-for-selected` in the `paper-radio-group` for example `value`

```
<paper-radio-group attr-for-selected="value">
  <paper-radio-button value="one" name="same_name">Label for one</paper-radio-button>
  <paper-radio-button value="two" name="same_name">Label for two</paper-radio-button>
</paper-radio-group>
```

Leaving my answer here as this was the hit i get while googling and might be of value to others.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the paper elements as a drop-in replacement for form input fields without writing any JavaScript, than i think you cannot, because they are nothing more than styled *divs*.

The *name* attribute of a *paper-radio-button* is its value. The currently selected button is specified with the *selected* attribute of the *paper-radio-group* and can be bound to an element property. You can then either use an attribute watcher or access this value when you need it. If you give *paper-radio-group* an *id*, say *radio*, you can also get the selected item directly with `this.$.radio.selected`.

Here is a small example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src='http://www.polymer-project.org/components/platform/platform.js'></script>
  <link rel='import' href='http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-radio-group/paper-radio-group.html'>
</head>

<body unresolved>

  <polymer-element name="my-app">
    <template>
      <paper-radio-group selected="{{selection}}">
        <paper-radio-button name="small" label="Small"></paper-radio-button>
        <paper-radio-button name="medium" label="Medium"></paper-radio-button>
        <paper-radio-button name="large" label="Large"></paper-radio-button>
      </paper-radio-group>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer('my-app', {
        created: function () { 
          this.selection = "medium" 
        },
        selectionChanged: function () { 
          console.log(this.selection); 
        }
      });
    </script>
  </polymer-element>

  <my-app></my-app>

</body>
</html>
```