# Polymer Paper radio group post value

Tags: php, polymer-1.0

i've implemented radio group buttons into my form and a i wish to post the selected value into php to process a search request, however i noticed that the buttons natively push their value as on ie 'selectedButton=on' for the php document i would like them to post their own name ie 'selectedButton = selectedButton' i have managed to do this by setting their values as names but this causes all items to be selectable

```
   <paper-radio-group>
      <form id="searchForm" is="iron-form" method="POST" action="search.php">
            <paper-radio-button name="Toyota">Toyota</paper-radio-button> <br>
            <paper-radio-button name="Mitsubishi">Mitsubishi</paper-radio-button> <br>
            <paper-radio-button name="Subaru">Subaru</paper-radio-button> <br>
            <paper-radio-button name="Nissan">Nissan</paper-radio-button> <br>
            <paper-radio-button name="BMW">BMW</paper-radio-button> <br>
            </form>
    </paper-radio-group>
        <paper-button raised type="submit"  on-click="_submit">Search</paper-button>
  </paper-card>
```

Script

```
<script>
     'use strict';
        (function() {
          Polymer({
            is:         'search-form',
            properties: {
              status:     String
            },
            listeners:  {
              'iron-form-submit': '_formSubmit',
              'iron-form-response': '_formResponse',
              'iron-form-error': '_formError'
            },
            _submit: function(event) {
              this.$.searchForm.submit();
            },
            _formSubmit: function(event) {
              this.status = 'Submitted...'
              console.log('The form has been submited.', event);
            },
            _formResponse: function(event) {
              this.status = 'Completed ' + event.detail.xhr.response;
              console.log('Form responded:', event.detail.xhr.response);
            },
            _formError: function(event) {
              this.status = 'Errored: ' + event.detail
              console.log('Form error:', event.detail);
            },

            attached: function() {
              this.status = ' ';
            }
            created: function () { 
          this.selection = "medium" 
        },
        selectionChanged: function () { 
          console.log(this.selection); 
        }
          });

        })();

</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the response yes i have tried that but the issue is that all radio buttons become select-able instead of only one at a time but yes this does help me get the vehicle name

Comment: I deleted my comment about giving them the same group name but with value. I thought I was wrong. See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24906031/polymer-paper-radio-group-how-to-have-multiple-radio-buttons-with-the-same-nam and if it helps.

Comment: would the above script work correctly?

Comment: I don't know, as I said; I've never worked with polymer before. Try it out and see.

Comment: sadly it throws exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

noticed that i couldn't directly select a value like in native radio button's 
so i changed the code to submit car:model and figured the rest in php

```
 <paper-radio-group selected="{{brand}}">
          <paper-radio-button name="toyota">Toyota</paper-radio-button>
          <paper-radio-button name="bmw">BMW</paper-radio-button>
          <paper-radio-button name="subaru">Subaru</paper-radio-button>
          <paper-radio-button name="mitsubishi">Mitsubishi</paper-radio-button>
          <paper-radio-button name="nissan">Nissan</paper-radio-button>
          <paper-radio-button name="mazda">Mazda</paper-radio-button>
          <paper-radio-button name="chrysler">Chrysler</paper-radio-button>
        </paper-radio-group>
        <paper-button raised type="submit"  on-click="_submit">Search</paper-button>
```

Script

```
<script>
 'use strict';
  (function() {
    Polymer({
      is: 'search-form',
      properties: {

        brand:      {
          type:       String,
          value:      'toyota'
        }
      },
      listeners:  {
        'iron-form-presubmit': '_formPresubmit',
        'iron-form-submit': '_formSubmit',
        'iron-form-response': '_formResponse',
        'iron-form-error': '_formError'
      },

      _submit: function(event) {
        this.$['the-form'].submit();

      },
      _formPresubmit: function() {
        this.$['the-form'].request.params = { brand: this.brand };
      },

      _formSubmit: function(event) {
      }

    });
  })();
</script>
```

hope this helps